# I am not able to install python mediapipe library on mac

Tags: python, mediapipe

As I tried to use pip to install mediapipe in my virtual environment, I run this in my terminal:

```
(venv) (base) stu-S2-19r:FaceDetector S2$ pip install mediapipe
```

And  got this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe
```

I am currently running:
Python 3.7.7, pip 21.0.1  on Mac OS Version 10.14.6.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO, please could you edit your question to include the command line

Comment: Try running `pip3 install mediapipe` as using pip can sometimes call python 2's package manager

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You need to make sure you are running a version of Mac OS that is Catalina or higher.